# How do I get the value from my custom widget?

Tags: dojo

The following code is a confirm dialog that contains "OK" and "Cancel" button, I would like to retrieve the value either user selected "OK" or "Cancel".

```
dojo.provide("custom.dialog.ConfirmDialog"); 
dojo.declare("custom.dialog.ConfirmDialog",dijit.Dialog , {
    message : "",
    postCreate: function(){ 
      var self = this; 
      this.inherited(arguments);

      this.contentCenter = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({ content : this.message, region: "center"});      
      this.contentBottom = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({region: "bottom"});


      this.okButton = new dijit.form.Button( { label: "OK" } ); 
      this.cancelButton = new dijit.form.Button( { label: "Cancel" } );      

      this.contentBottom.addChild(this.okButton);
      this.contentBottom.addChild(this.cancelButton);

      this.addChild(this.contentCenter);
      this.addChild(this.contentBottom);

      this.okButton.on('click', function(e){ 
        self.emit('dialogconfirmed', { bubbles: false } ); 
        self.destroy(); 
        return "OK";
      }); 
      this.cancelButton.on('click', function(e){ 
        self.emit('dialogdeclined', { bubbles: false } ); 
        self.destroy(); 
        return "Cancel";
      }); 
    } 
});
```

But there was nothing returned, please help me out if you can point out my mistake, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access the value in event listener?  You can pass the label as part of the arguments.

```
self.emit('dialogconfirmed', 
    { bubbles: false, label: self.okButton.get('label') } );
```

Usage:

```
this.confirmDialog.on('dialogconfirmed', function(data) {
    var label = data.label;
});
```